# How to split a line into paragraphs JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I have a string that is passed through props. It may consist of several sentences. Can I implement splitting this line inside one tag? Maybe through replacement? The end always - (.). I`m using React

```
const name = "It is just text 1. It is just text 2. It is just text 3."
<p>{name}</p>
```

I would like to get -

It is just text 1.
It is just text 2.
It is just text 3.

Comment: Does your line always end with a dot (.)?

Comment: `<p>{name}</p>` This looks like JSX, Are you using any framework?

Comment: Always end (.) and yes, I`m using react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to split the string into an array based on `.` as the delimeter.

```
name.split(".").map(p => <p>{p}.</p>);
```

Assuming you're using React.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is to have one sentence per one paragraph, then you'd need to cut the initial message to parts and provide several `<p>` tags.

```
const name = "It is just text 1. It is just text 2. It is just text 3."
const sentences = name.split(". ")

{
  sentences.map(
    sentence => <p>{sentence + "."}</p>
  )
}

Output:
<p>It is just text 1.</p>
<p>It is just text 2.</p>
<p>It is just text 3.</p>
```